# Beautiful Soup and Pandas extract number

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have this structure:

```
<tr id="table3620_0_5" class="l1">
            <td class="r">       North America</td>
            <td x:num="02/12/20">02/12/20</td>
            <td x:num="" class="r">5553226</td>
            <td x:num="" class="r">TEST TWI</td>
            <td x:num="0.03365930063626542">3.37 %</td>
            <td/>
            <td x:num="0.03365930063626542">3.37 %</td>
         </tr>
```

With pandas read html I can extract the table but I'm interested in x:num value instead of the value of the tag. I'm trying to explore a solution with Beautiful Soup as well, but I came up with nothing as of now

Answer (score 2):

You can try `beautifulsoup`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

s = """<tr id="table3620_0_5" class="l1">
            <td class="r">       North America</td>
            <td x:num="02/12/20">02/12/20</td>
            <td x:num="" class="r">5553226</td>
            <td x:num="" class="r">TEST TWI</td>
            <td x:num="0.03365930063626542">3.37 %</td>
            <td/>
            <td x:num="0.03365930063626542">3.37 %</td>
         </tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

output = [i.get('x:num') for i in soup.findAll("td", {"x:num" : True})]

print(output)
```

```
['02/12/20', '', '', '0.03365930063626542', '0.03365930063626542']
```

---

```
output[-2:]
```

```
['0.03365930063626542', '0.03365930063626542']
```

Comment: I'm trying to extract only the last two x:num the rest above should be the usual value tag

Comment: what about `output[-2:]` ?